# django rest serializer to_representation failing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Im messing around with django rest framework and its serializers, and im running into an error when overriding  the create method.

serializer

```
class AdddTestModel(serializers.Serializer):
name = serializers.CharField()
score = serializers.FloatField()
score2 = serializers.FloatField()
song = serializers.IntegerField()


def create(self, validated_data):
    print(validated_data["song"])
    song = Song.objects.get(id=validated_data["song"])
    print(song)
    instance = TestModel.objects.create(name=validated_data["name"], score = validated_data["score"], score2 = validated_data["score2"], song = song)
    return instance


def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super().to_representation(instance)
    return representation
```

View

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def addTestModel(request):
    serializer = AdddTestModel(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        
        print(serializer.data)
        return Response("hello", status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response("Error", status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

I had everything working correctly when I was using a modelSerializer, but wanted to experiment with serializer.Serializer.

I know the create method is working as the TestModel object is being persisted into my db.

The error seems to be coming from the to_representation method, specifically

```
representation = super().to_representation(instance)
```

The error i am getting is the following

```
Internal Server Error: /api/addTest/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\realestate\theFirstView\api\views.py", line 53, in addTestModel
    print(serializer.data)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 555, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 253, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 522, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py", line 915, in to_representation
    return int(value)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Song'
```

I know using serializers.ModelSerializer makes more sense here, but i'm just wondering if there is any specific reason why this is working with serializers.ModelSerializer but not serializers.serializer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are handling the payload params to business models in your create correctly, but not doing the exact opposite when serializing a response. You must explicitly define that you want song id as the value of song-field.

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    return {
         "song": instance.song.id,
         # rest ...
    }
```

Edit:

You could of course use serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField for song-field to probably do this conversion without any extra hustle. It would give you model object directly in the validated data when deserializing, and pk as value when serializing.